# Azure Pipelines Environment variables not working for PowerShell on Target Machines

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-pipelines

I’m unable to get the environment variables (for example `$env:RELEASE_RELEASENAME`) for a task that runs a PowerShell script on a target machine, however, the env variables work for PowerShell Inline.

Does getting `env` variables from PowerShell on target machines need special treatment or am I missing something here?

Comment: Check if these environment variables are targeted as `Machine`. If they are targeted `User` only that user can get their values. Environment variables can also be targeted `Process` and in that case they are only available for the process that set them. See [EnvironmentVariableTarget Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environmentvariabletarget?view=netframework-4.8) and [SetEnvironmentVariable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environmentvariabletarget)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, I met this problem with Ubuntu hosted agent. My solution is to manually add the environment, then I can get the environment variable in inline script or script file.

[image]